# I have no idea how to solve this

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, systems-of-equations

There are $14$ more cookies than biscuits in a jar of $38$ cookies and biscuits. How many cookies are in the jar?

Comment: Hello, M.Hesham, and welcome to Math StackExchange. The custom on this site is that we ask you to please give some background and context for problems like this. Even if you have no idea where to start, we can better provide a good answer to your question if you tell us a bit about what you've learned and what confuses you. Did your teacher describe a technique that you remember a bit, but aren't sure how to apply, for example?

Comment: ...AND you need to make titles that describe you *problem*, not your *reaction* to the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn't a site that will solve your homework for you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 3):

Solve the following system. $$x-y=14$$ and $$x+y=38$$

Comment: mathematicians are weird people they transform cookies and biscuits into latin alphabet lol

Answer (score 0):

Think of starting with a jar of $38$ cookies and no biscuits, and  turning cookies into biscuits one by one.  Each time you do this you reduce the excess of cookies over biscuits by $2$.  How many times would you have to do it to make that excess be $14$?

Answer (score 0):

A non algebraic technique useful for simpler word problems: *hypothesise*, i.e. start with *Suppose...*

Suppose you removed those "extra" $14$ cookies.

What's the total number of snacks now?

Can you see that the remaining biscuits and cookies are now equal in number?

Can you figure out how many cookies you have now?

Can you work out how many you started with before you removed $14$?